# What maintenance does a cedar deck require?

Tags: deck, maintenance

We just moved into a house with a very nice 16'x16' cedar screened porch. The problem is I've never had a cedar deck and am not sure what maintenance to expect or how often to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cedar is naturally rot-resistant, but not 100% rot proof. **Keep it clean & dry.**

Leaves are especially good at promoting rot. They are design to turn in to new soil to feed the tree they fall from, so they rot fast. If they clump up on your deck, they will hold moisture & invite fungus to break them down. That will hurt your deck, too.

In general, look for anything that will hold moisture against your deck. Yard debris, a door mat, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat it with something like johnson's watersealer.  Ceder is resistant to bugs and water, but will fade out and wear some over the years. a good sealer will perk it up and make it last longer, also you can tint the color that way some if you want.

If your porch is covered and screened, you probably don't have to worry too much, but may want to apply something to the outside.